# Como serializar um formulário com checkbox

Tags: javascript

Nesse script ele calcula o total dos valores dos checkbox marcados, qual adaptação seria necessária para além da soma ele também mostrar os atributos `name` e `value` das respectivas checkboxes marcadas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML:**

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste" checked="" value="20.00" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste" checked="" value="20.00" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste" checked="" value="20.00" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste" checked="" value="20.00" />

    <div id='resultado_soma'>
        <?echo $total?>
    </div>
    <!--Resultado da soma dos 
 checkbox-->
    <div id='resultado_soma_menos_variavel'>
        <?echo $total_geral?>
    </div>
    <!-- 
 Resultado Pegando      
 a Variavel - Resultado checkbox -->
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado_soma');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener('change', calcular);
    }

    function calcular() {
        var dados = [].map.call(elements, function(input) {
            return {
            el: input,
                value: parseInt(input.value),
                name: input.name
            };
        });
        var total = dados.reduce(function(soma, el) {
            return soma + (el.el.checked ? el.value : 0);
        }, 0);

        resultado.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dados) + ' ' + total;
    }
})();
```

Comment: Esses checkbox não têm `name`...

Comment: desculpa não coloquei...

Comment: Não é bem claro o que precisas... dá uma olhada aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/s2uw6n57/ e tenta clarificar a pergunta.

Comment: Então  se voce clicar no primeiro box ele tera que me mostrar o nome dele e o valor . e ai por diante

Comment: Fábio, e mostrar onde? Ainda não melhoraste a pergunta... para mostrar respeito a quem gasta tempo a ajudar é desejável que a pergunta seja clara, com código.

Comment: coloquei uma imagem acima

Comment: Seria mais fácil colocar todos dentro de um form e serializar... Aí só pegaria os marcados, e pegaria o name e value

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s2uw6n57/1/ tá ai...

Comment: Isso mesmo parceiro....  só que o calculo teria que vir em uma saida separada

Comment: Ambos estão alocados em variáveis distintas `total` e `dados` ou seja você pode colocar ela na saída que desejar...

Comment: Amigo Não tenho conhecimento de javascript como posso tratar essa saida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas dá uma olhada nisso:

Primeira coisa, dar um nome DIFERENTE para cada checkbox: teste1, teste2, teste3 etc...

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="teste1" value="20.00" />
<input type="checkbox" name="teste2" value="20.00" />
<input type="checkbox" name="teste3" value="20.00" />
<input type="checkbox" name="teste4" value="20.00" />
```

Depois, onde tem:

```
resultado.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dados) + ' ' + total;
```

Trocar por:

```
//resultado.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dados) + ' ' + total;
   resultado.innerHTML = $("#form").serialize().replace(/&/g, '<br />') + '<br /><br />R$ ' + total.toFixed(2).replace(".",",");
```

Veja que comentei a primeira linha (a que tinha antes) porque não sei o que você quer fazer com isso.

Teste aqui nesse Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s2uw6n57/3/

Comment: Exatamente isso David , só preciso que a soma apareça em um div separada

Comment: @FabioHenrique Basta criar mais uma div `<div id="resultado"></div>` e trocar `resultado.innerHTML` por `document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML`.

Comment: Tentei aqui mais continua vindo tudo na mesma div coloque aqui uma imagem como queria http://i.imgur.com/1kqQILb.jpg

Comment: Desculpa minha ignorância mais eu não sei nada de javascript

Comment: @FabioHenrique Entendi. Dá uma olhada nesse Fiddle que atualizei: https://jsfiddle.net/s2uw6n57/5/

Comment: Perfeito agora... Obrigado